# Confused about alias_maps and virtual_alias_maps

Tags: debian, email, postfix, sendmail, alias

I have already re-read the docs on this as well as other posts here and this is still very unclear to me. I have been testing various things to understand the difference between `alias_maps` and `virtual_alias_maps` and I don't see the use of these 2 separate settings in postfix. This is what I found so far *(Note - I am using postfix in the same server as my web server as null client to send emails only)*:

1) **/etc/aliases file:**

```
root: me@somedomain.com
```

When I add the above to the `alias_maps`, I noticed that some services like fail2ban are able to pick this and it sends root emails to the alias email addresses mentioned. However, I also noticed that some other services (like `mail` command) does not respect this and tries to send the email directly to root@mydomain.com which does not exist (I think its the postfix `myorigin` setting that is adding the @mydomain.com). To fix this I then added the `virtual_alias_maps`

2) **/etc/postfix/virtual**

```
root     me@someotherdomain.com
```

When the above is added, all services uses this virtual aliases email. I also noticed that once I add the above, even fail2ban begins to ignore my initial settings in `/etc/aliases/` file and starts to follow the email address given in virtual file.

**Now this has confused me even more -**

1. Why do we need `/etc/aliases/` when having the email inside virtual aliases map seems to override it?
2. What is the purpose of having these 2 separate aliases mapping and when do we decide when to use what?
3. Why did fail2ban (which is configured to email to `root@localhost`) first follow email address given in `alias_maps` (/etc/aliases/) and later decides to ignore that once `virtual_alias_maps` was added?
4. Why doesn't all services read email aliases mentioned in /etc/aliases and they only work when the email aliases are added in virtual alias map?

I have spend several hours since yesterday and still unsure. Can someone help me clear my confusion?

**EDIT:**
This is the mail log when email is sent to root using `mail root` command. The aliases email for root is mentioned in /etc/aliases/. But mail does not work until I move this root aliases email from `aliases_maps` to `virtual_aliases_maps`

Log when root email alias is mentioned in `/etc/aliases/`:

```
Nov 14 16:39:27 Debian postfix/pickup[4339]: 0F12643432: uid=0 from=<root>

Nov 14 16:39:27 Debian postfix/cleanup[4495]: 0F12643432: message-id=<20141114110927.0F12643432@Debian.domainname.com>

Nov 14 16:39:27 Debian postfix/qmgr[4338]: 0F12643432: from=<root@domainname.com>, size=517, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Nov 14 16:39:27 Debian postfix/error[4496]: 0F12643432: to=<root@domainname.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0/0/0.01, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to domainname.com[128.199.147.136]:25: Connection refused)
```

This is the log after the email aliases for root is moved from `/etc/aliases/` to `/etc/postfix/virtual` where the email delivery is successful after the change:

```
Nov 14 16:44:58 Debian postfix/pickup[4545]: ADD9A43436: uid=0 from=<root>

Nov 14 16:44:58 Debian postfix/cleanup[4563]: ADD9A43436: message-id=<20141114111458.ADD9A43436@Debian.domainname.com>

Nov 14 16:44:58 Debian postfix/qmgr[4544]: ADD9A43436: from=<root@domainname.com>, size=453, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Nov 14 16:45:00 Debian postfix/smtp[4551]: ADD9A43436: to=<admin@somesite.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=somesite.com[108.160.157.120]:25, delay=1.9, delays=0.03/0/0.97/0.88, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1XpEqC-0002ry-9s)

Nov 14 16:45:00 Debian postfix/qmgr[4544]: ADD9A43436: removed
```

Comment: `I also noticed that some other services (like mail command) does not respect this` --> please show the maillog entry related to this condition

Comment: @masegaloeh Have updated my post with the mail log

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### Some background

Postfix inherited some features from older sendmail like milter and aliases. The file `/etc/aliases` is part of `aliases` inheritance and implemented by `alias_maps`. On the other side, postfix has `virtual_maps`/`virtual_alias_maps` for handle  email aliasing. So what's the difference between them?

### Parameter `alias_maps`

- Used only for [local(8) delivery](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps)
- According to [address class in postfix](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html), email will delivery by local(8) *if the recipient domain names are listed in the `mydestination`*
- The [lookup input](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) was only local parts from full email addres (e.g myuser from myuser@example.com). It discard domain parts of recipient.
- The [lookup result](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) can contains one or more of the following:

  - **email address**: email will forwarded to *email address*
  - **/file/name**: email will be appended to */file/name*
  - **|command**: mail piped to the *command*
  - **:include:/file/name**: include alias from */file/name*

### Parameter `virtual_alias_maps`

- Used by [virtual(5) delivery](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps)
- Always [invoked first time](http://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=107291577315123&w=2) before any other address classes. It doesn't care whether the recipient domain was listed in `mydestination`, `virtual_mailbox_domains` or other places. It will override the address/alias defined in other places.
- The [lookup input](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) has some format

  - **user@domain**: it will match *user@domain* literally
  - **user**: it will match *user*@site when site is equal to `$myorigin`, when site is listed in `$mydestination`, or when it is listed in `$inet_interfaces` or `$proxy_interfaces`. *This  functionality  overlaps  with  functionality  of the local aliases(5) database.*
  - **@domain**: it will match any email intended for `domain` regardless of local parts
- The [lookup result](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) must be

  - valid email address
  - user without domain. Postfix will append `$myorigin` if `append_at_myorigin` set *yes*

---

> Why do we need /etc/aliases when having the email inside virtual aliases map seems to override it?

As you can see above, `alias_maps`(/etc/aliases) has some additional features (beside forwarding) like piping to command. In contrast with `virtual_alias_maps` that just forwards emails.

> What is the purpose of having these 2 separate aliases mapping and when do we decide when to use what?

The `alias_maps` drawback is that you cannot differentiate if the original recipient has *root@example.com* or *root@example.net*. Both will be mapped to root entry in `alias_maps`. In other words, you can define different forwarding address with `virtual_alias_maps`.

> Why did fail2ban (which is configured to email to root@localhost) first follow email address given in alias_maps (/etc/aliases/) and later decides to ignore that once virtual_alias_maps was added?

**Before virtual_alias_maps added**: root@localhost was aliased by `alias_maps` because localhost was listed in `mydestination`.

**After virtual_alias_maps defined**: The entry `root` (in virtual_alias_maps) doesn't have domain parts and localhost was listed in `mydestination`, so it will match `root me@example.com`.

> Why doesn't all services read email aliases mentioned in /etc/aliases and they only work when the email aliases are added in virtual alias map?

Command `mail root` will send email to root. Because lacks of domain parts, [postfix trivial-rewrite](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#standard) will append myorigin to domain parts. So, mail will be send to **root@myorigin**.

**Before virtual_alias_maps added**: Unfortunately, `myorigin` isn't listed in `mydestination`, so it won't be processed by `alias_maps`.

**After virtual_alias_maps added**: The entry `root` (in virtual_alias_maps) doesn't have domain parts and myorigin (obviously) same as `myorigin`, so it will match `root me@example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `/etc/aliases` is there primarily for local delivery, for example, mail to root from cron, etc, it's nice to keep your local aliases separate, `virtual_alias_maps` can also be used with SQL DBs, and so on.
2. `virtual_alias_maps` is for when you have virtual users (and virtual domains), often that do not map to system users, but if you don't have virtual domains, and very few users, that sort of functionality may not be necessary.
3. fail2ban doesn't care, it just submits email to the MTA.
4. You need to be more specific, which services, how and where do they submit mail?

Comment: Thank you @NickW couple of things: (1) For No:4, mail command is one of the service that does this. I mean if /etc/aliases is primarily for local delivery to local users, shouldnt `mail root` command should actually fall under this category? Why isint this service considering the info in /etc/aliases when its a local delivery? (2) Considering these for my scenario, is it then a good practice to have the user aliases email addresses mentioned in both `/etc/aliases` as well as `virtual_alias_maps` so they work for everything?

Comment: 1. Ok, the mail command should use `/etc/aliases` by default, a really stupid question, you did run `newaliases` after updating the file, right?  2. I would say that is overkill, if people will be receiving mail from the local machine, it would be worth configuring the scripts to use their proper email address, that way it will be routed through postfix, and delivered to the correct destination.

Comment: hi @NickW yes I did rebuilt aliases using `newaliases` after change. The only thing I can think for why its not using aliases is maybe due to the postfix setting that adds `@$domain_name` after the user and hence `virtual_alias_maps` is needed to redirect those emails. I read this in postfix docs and maybe thats why `mail` command to root is not working with `aliases`: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#some_local Anyhow, thank you so much for helping me understand this better Nick. I really appreciate it.. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped :)