# Integrating postfix with LDAP to eMail Users with Access to A Specific Host

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, openldap

I have a working openLDAP v3 installation under Ubuntu 14.04 (`slapd 2.4.31-1`) with `phpldapadmin`, `sudo-ldap` and other packages installed. I'm trying to integrate `postfix` with LDAP so I can send emails to users@host2.example.com or users@host10.example.com for example.

## Current Setup

As part of this setup I have `host` attributes for each host a user is allowed access to (or is simply a `*` for allowing access to all hosts). I use this on my ldap clients to grant or deny access to particular hosts. Also associated with each user is their corporate email address in the `mail` attribute. An example LDIF for a user is given below:

```
dn: uid=auser,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
cn: A User
displayname: A User
gecos: A User
gidnumber: 1011
givenname: A
homedirectory: /home/auser
host: host1
host: host2
host: host3
host: host4
mailacceptinggeneralid: root
loginshell: /bin/bash
mail: a.user@example.com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: shadowAccount
objectclass: hostObject
objectclass: postfixUser
objectclass: top
sn: User
uid: auser
uidnumber: 1001
```

### Postfix Lookups of User Email Addresses in LDAP

I have a `/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf` file with the following contents for achieving this:

```
server_host = ldap.example.com
search_base = dc=example, dc=com

# look for entries with this
query_filter = (|(uid=%s)(mailacceptinggeneralid=%s)(mail=%s@example.com))

# what attribute from the search result is returned
result_attribute = mail

# the format in which the result is returned
result_format = %s
```

This configuration works so far and is confirmed with the following `postmap` commands returning the addresses I expect:

```
# A query using the uid of the user
postmap -q auser ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-mail.cf
a.user@example.com

# A query using the corporate username
postmap -q a.user ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-mail.cf
a.user@example.com

# A query for a user specified in mailacceptinggeneralid
postmap -q root ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-mail.cf
a.user@example.com
```

## Postfix Lookups of Users with Access to a Host

I want to be able to send emails to `users@host2.example.com` for example, and have the addresses pulled from LDAP for all users who have access to `host2` (i.e. `host` attribute is set to `host2` or `*`. This I where I need some help.

So far, I have a file `/etc/postfix/ldap-host-users.cf` which contains:

```
server_host = ldap.example.com
search_base = dc=example, dc=com
query_filter = (|(host=%3)(host=\*))
result_attribute = mail
result_format = %s
```

It assumes the query contains the FQDN, but I think `postfix` only uses the `username` (possibly due to me using `alias_maps` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`?). Anyway, testing the above:

```
postmap -q users@host2.example.com ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-host-users.cf
a.user@example.com

# The following also returns a list of email addresses, but shouldn't:
postmap -q any_group@host2.example.com ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-host-users.cf
a.user@example.com
```

## postconf -n Output

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-mail.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-host-users.cf
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.example.com, , localhost
myhostname = host2.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

## Questions

- Does `postfix` only query using the local `username` and doesn't include the FQDN in the query?

  - Is this because I'm using `alias_maps` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`?
- Can I somehow check that the `username` part of the query is `users` and return nothing if it is something else?
  e.g. In `query_filter` can I do something like `%u="users"`?
- Is there a better/different way to achieve this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the output of `postconf -n`.

Comment: @masegaloeh done :)

Answer (score 3):

Some partial answers:

> **1. Does postfix only query using the local username and doesn't include the FQDN in the query? Is this because I'm using `alias_maps` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`?**

**YES**, according [`alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps) documentation, we need to refer on [man 5 aliases](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) to know the syntax details.

> **The  name  is a local address (no domain part)**.  Use double quotes when the name contains any special characters such as whitespace, `#',`:',
>   or  `@'.  The  name  is  folded to lowercase, in order to make database lookups case insensitive.

So, this is an expected behavior from postfix.

---

> **3. Is there a better/different way to achieve this?**

Use [virtual_alias_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps). According to this answer on [Confused about alias_maps and virtual_alias_maps](https://serverfault.com/a/644393/218590), `virtual_alias_maps` will "user@domain" as input.

Comment: For your second question, I don't fully understand what do you mean :). Would you like to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Some clarification added.

Comment: Ah, looks like I understand what you mean. Unfortunately, I'm not LDAP guru. Parameter `query_filter` in postfix follows [RFC2254](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2254) syntax

Comment: Yeah, looks like it doesn't do what I want. I'm starting to think I'm approaching this the wrong way but I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: Can you explain 'Yeah, looks like it doesn't do what I want'? What changes do you apply to original setup?